# Stopping the Orchestrator does not stop the Durable Function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am using some of the features offered by Azure in the following manner :

- I have an **orhestrator**
- I have a **"durable function"** activity, called by the orchestrator (only one; it's a simple design)
- I start and stop the orchestrator with the **"_HttpStart"** function generated by the VS template (it has HttpTrigger and DurableClient).

so far so good. I see in app insights that the orchetrator starts, and in turn starts the durable function activity.

**Problem :** the activity is very long (over 20 minutes) and **I see that the activity continues running all the way to the end, long after I successfully stop the orchestrator** by using the "terminatePostUri" endpoint of the _HttpStart function.

**Is that by design?**

Side note: All I want is "a function that runs for a long time". It doesn' seem to me that a regular Azure Function (as opposed to a Durable Function) fits the bill but if I'm mistaken then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is that by design?**

Yes, It is by design.
As Mentioned in the document [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=csharp#terminate-instances).

> Instance termination doesn't currently propagate. Activity functions and sub-orchestrations run to completion, regardless of whether you've terminated the orchestration instance that called them.

But I have used another workaround. It stopped my orchestration function.
I have used default sample code and just added some wait time to add time in the Orchestration function.

**`function.cs`:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
   
   namespace FunctionApp1
   {
       public class TerminateRequest
       {
           public string InstanceIdToStop { get; set; }
       }
       public static class Function
       {
           [FunctionName("Function")]
           public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
               [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
           {
               var outputs = new List<string>();
   
               outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo"));
               await context.CreateTimer(context.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddSeconds(60),CancellationToken.None);
               outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Seattle"));
               outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "London"));
   
               return outputs;
           }
   
           [FunctionName(nameof(SayHello))]
           public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
           {
               log.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
               return $"Hello {name}!";
           }
   
           [FunctionName("Function_HttpStart")]
           public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
               [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
               [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
               ILogger log)
           {
               string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function", null);
   
               log.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);
   
               return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
           }
   
           [FunctionName("Function_stop_Orchestration")]
           public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Stop(
           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
           [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client,
           ILogger log)
           {
               // Function input comes from the request content.
               TerminateRequest terminateRequest = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<TerminateRequest>();
               string instanceIdToStop = terminateRequest.InstanceIdToStop;
   
               // Terminate the specified orchestration.
               try
               {
                   await client.TerminateAsync(instanceIdToStop, "Terminated by user request");
                   log.LogInformation($"Terminated orchestration with ID = '{instanceIdToStop}'.");
                   return req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, $"Terminated orchestration with ID = '{instanceIdToStop}'.");
               }
               catch(Exception ex) 
               {
                   log.LogError($"Orchestration with ID = '{instanceIdToStop}' {ex.Message}");
                   return req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound, $"Orchestration with ID = '{instanceIdToStop}' not found or could not be terminated.");
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

I passed Instance ID manually to stop the Orchestration function.

**`Output`:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]